# Get view count of playlist with YouTube API

Tags: youtube-data-api

So, I didn't even know that playlists have a separate view count, but they do, here ya go: 
[image: Youtube Plyalist]
Or here's the link, cuz it took me a while to find it, if you don't believe me: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG

Anyone knows if I can retrieve the view count of a PLAYLIST, with the YT data API? I have tried v3/playlistItems, v3/playlists, neither did contain this information. And FYI they do NOT accept the 'statistics' in the part parameter.

Hope someone has this figured out!
Thanks!